# Meaning of the angle brackets in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Even though the question is quite wide I am actually curious regarding one case I sow recently while using the [Realm library](https://realm.io/). As I previously used the protocols(delegate) on many occasions and also imported classes using <>. And now this is the line the code I don't completely understand or don't understand at all if I am mistaking:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray <ExerciseLog *><ExerciseLog> * exerciseLogs;
```

I suppose that the second part of the line `<ExerciseLog> * exerciseLogs` is used to ensure that exerciseLogs may be an instance of any ExerciseLog that conforms to the ExerciseLog protocol, is my assumption correct?

Or simple said if the user send a different object then the expected one, the app won't crash, and that a default value will be assigned.

And this part I am guessing, the  is some sort of safe casting so that the returned object confirms to the ExerciseLog.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of Obj-C protocol conformance and generics. [RLMArray](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html) is declared as

```
@interface RLMArray < RLMObjectType : RLMObject * >  : NSObject<RLMCollection,NSFastEnumeration>
```

it has one generic argument. That's the `<ExerciseLog *>`.

The second part `<ExerciseLog>` is conformance to protocol of the given type.

By the way, that protocol is declared using `RLM_ARRAY_TYPE` macro. The code seems to be a bit complicated but it was probably an older way to enforce element type for arrays (`RLMArray<protocolX>` is not assignable to `RLMArray<protocolY>`).

Quoting the documentation:

> Unlike an NSArray, RLMArrays hold a single type, specified by the objectClassName property. This is referred to in these docs as the “type” of the array.
>
> When declaring an RLMArray property, the type must be marked as conforming to a protocol by the same name as the objects it should contain (see the RLM_ARRAY_TYPE macro). RLMArray properties can also use Objective-C generics if available. For example:

Answer (score 1):

The angle brackets in a class interface definition indicates the protocols that your class is conforming to.

A protocol is almost like an interface in Java or C#, with the addition that methods in an Objective-C protocol can be optional.

Additionaly in Objective-C you can declare a variable, argument or instance variable to conform to several protocols as well. Example

NSObject *myVariable;
In this case the class must be NSObject or a subclass (only NSProxy and its subclasses would fail), and it must also conform to both NSCoding and UITableViewDelegate protocols.

In Java or C# this would only be possible by actually declaring said class.